Вывести именно ethernet MAC address
Мне нужно передать в string переменную blueprint ue5 ethernet MAC address из c++, но выводиться не тот который нужен а последний из списка адаптеров.
#include "A_MySQL.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")

void AA_MySQL::MacAdress(FString& addr)
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo;
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);
    char* mac_addr = (char*)malloc(18);

    AdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    if (AdapterInfo == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
        free(mac_addr);
    }

    if (GetAdaptersInfo(AdapterInfo, &dwBufLen) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW) {
        free(AdapterInfo);
        AdapterInfo = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO*)malloc(dwBufLen);
        if (AdapterInfo == NULL) {
            printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersinfo\n");
            free(mac_addr);
        }
    }

    if (GetAdaptersInfo(AdapterInfo, &dwBufLen) == NO_ERROR) {
        PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;
        while (pAdapterInfo) {
            if (pAdapterInfo->Type == MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET)
            {
                do {
                    sprintf(mac_addr, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                        pAdapterInfo->Address[0], pAdapterInfo->Address[1],
                        pAdapterInfo->Address[2], pAdapterInfo->Address[3],
                        pAdapterInfo->Address[4], pAdapterInfo->Address[5]);
                    addr = mac_addr;
                    pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;
                } while (pAdapterInfo);
            }
        }
    }
    free(AdapterInfo);
}

